# How can I count the number of posts?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Here is my table structure:

```
-- reputations
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+
| id | post_id     | user_id | score | reputation | date_time  |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+ -- Suppose:
| 1  | 1           | 1       | 1     | 5          | 1500489844 | -- out of last week
| 2  | 4           | 3       | -1    | -2         | 1500499815 | -- out of last week
| 3  | 2           | 3       | 1     | 5          | 1500584821 |
| 4  | 3           | 1       | 1     | 5          | 1501389166 |
| 5  | 2           | 4       | 1     | 5          | 1501399142 |
| 6  | 2           | 1       | -1    | -2         | 1501399142 |
| 7  | 4           | 1       | 0     | 15         | 1501481186 |
| 8  | 5           | 1       | 1     | 5          | 1501481297 |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+
-- Note: the last row came from an accepted-answer, that's why its score is 0

-- post_tag
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 2      |
| 1       | 4      |
| 2       | 2      |
| 3       | 1      |
| 3       | 4      |
| 4       | 3      |
| 5       | 1      |
+---------+--------+

-- tags
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | php    |
| 2  | html   |
| 3  | css    |
| 4  | mysql  |
+----+--------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT
    t.tag, sum(r.reputation) AS tag_reputation, sum(r.score) AS tag_score
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN reputations r 
        ON r.user_id = u.id 
            AND r.date_time > 1500584821
    JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.post_id = r.post_id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE u.id = 1 -- Specific user: Jack
GROUP BY
    u.id, u.user_name, t.tag 
ORDER BY
    u.id, tag_reputation DESC;
```

And here is the current result:

```
tag   | tag_reputation |  tag_score
----: | :------------- | :---------
css   |             15 |          0
php   |             10 |          2
mysql |              5 |          1
html  |             -2 |         -1
```

As you can see, the result is a list of tags with reputations and scores for a specific user ordered by `tag_reputation`. **[Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ab096f4264d11bc377f978b67b6856ad)**

---

Now I want to also count the number of posts for each tag. So this is **the expected result**:

```
tag   | tag_reputation |  tag_score | post_num
----: | :------------- | :--------- | :-------
css   |             15 |          0 |        1
php   |             10 |          2 |        2
mysql |              5 |          1 |        1
html  |             -2 |         -1 |        1
```

How can I do that? I think I have to work on `post_id` column and `GROUP BY` clause. But I don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this using mobile phone so I cannot try it on the fiddle you gave. I modify your SQL to count number of post using `COUNT`.

```
SELECT
t.tag, 
sum(r.reputation) AS tag_reputation, 
sum(r.score) AS tag_score,
COUNT(DISTINCT pt.post_id) AS post_num
FROM
users u
LEFT JOIN reputations r 
    ON r.user_id = u.id 
        AND r.date_time > 1500584821
JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.post_id = r.post_id
JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE u.id = 1 -- Specific user: Jack
GROUP BY
u.id, u.user_name, t.tag 
ORDER BY
u.id, tag_reputation DESC;
```

Edit: I add COUNT with DISTINCT. See if it solve.

Comment: I've added one more row into `reputations` table with the same post id which already exists. But sadly `post_num` increased either. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5d92f3fdf78757136a7eaf04ebf01e30

Comment: In your new fiddle, you add new record in `reputations` table with same `post_id` (5)and same `user_id` (1) and you want this records not be counted?

Comment: Obviously not. Because the post_id (5) is duplicate and it is counted once.

Comment: But you want its reputation added?

Comment: Yes . . . . . .

Comment: Does it work? I am having trouble running fiddle on mobile phone.

Comment: Yes . . .  . . .

Answer (score 3):

Did you try adding the post id to the query?

I added `count(r.post_id) as post_num` in your `select` statement and it [gave the expected results](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3cf8ecc34adb9aa87053b75ad2865dff).

To remove duplicates, use `distinct`. Do you want the count with respect to tag table? Try

1. `COUNT(distinct pt.post_id) AS post_count`; or
2. `COUNT(distinct r.post_id) AS post_count`

Answer (score 0):

Some things about your expected results don't exactly line up - for example, your expected results include posts from before the date you excluded in your where clause, and the original query's results include results that aren't from user id = 1 so I am a bit confused overall but:

I think just adding:

```
SELECT
    t.tag, sum(r.reputation) AS tag_reputation, sum(r.score) AS tag_score, count(r.id) as post_num
```

should make this work?

If not, you can use a inline select in your select statement:

```
SELECT
    t.tag, sum(r.reputation) AS tag_reputation, sum(r.score) AS tag_score, 
    max((select count(r2.id) from users u2 
        LEFT JOIN reputations r2 ON r2.user_id = u2.id AND r2.date_time > 1500584821 
        JOIN post_tag pt2 ON pt2.post_id = r2.post_id 
        JOIN tags t2 ON t2.id = pt2.tag_id 
        where t.tag = t2.tag)) AS post_num
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN reputations r 
    ON r.user_id = u.id 
        AND r.date_time > 1500584821
JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.post_id = r.post_id
JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE u.id = 1 -- Specific user: Jack
GROUP BY
    u.id, u.user_name, t.tag 
ORDER BY
    u.id, tag_reputation DESC;
```